# UpperCasePipe ngModel not applying to the last character in input?

Tags: angular, angular2-ngmodel, ngmodel

I have the input defined as:

```
<input [ngModel]="value | uppercase" (ngModelChange)="value=$event">
```

As you can see in the Plunker, when typing into the field the last character typed does not get upcased.  Should I be handling this a different way?

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/264FHAlgX9xcpeDc9Glr?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You could do this instead:

```
<input [ngModel]="value" (ngModelChange)="value=$event.toUpperCase()">
```

Problem with your approach is that you are making the `value` uppercase only when you read it via the `[ngModel]`, you need to do this when setting it instead.

Another possibility would be to do this in controller, just declare the variable as setter.

Answer (score 1):

Value gets updated once the ngModel is changed. Instead, You can simply do this without using a pipe,

```
  <input [ngModel]="value " (ngModelChange)="value=$event.toUpperCase()">
```

**[`DEMO`](https://plnkr.co/edit/AdiFhRfb9XLclabFUCpw?p=preview)**